# Python найти по значению в списке словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[{"updated_at": 1591121708, "country_id": 215, "country_name": "Iran", "country_value": 7.18626},
{"updated_at": 1591121709, "country_id": 350, "country_name": "Mexico", "country_value": 14.92847},
{"updated_at": 1591121709, "country_id": 350, "country_name": "Mexico", "country_value": 14.92847},
{"updated_at": 1591121706, "country_id": 999, "country_name": "Russia", "country_value": 35.27485}]
```

Подскажите, как в вывести значение "country_value" из этого списка словарей, если я знаю значение "country_id" = 999?
Список получен после конвертации json с помощью json.loads()

Comment: Ну чутка головушку включите, базовые вещи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [{"updated_at": 1591121708, "country_id": 215,
         "country_name": "Iran", "country_value": 7.18626},
        {"updated_at": 1591121709, "country_id": 350,
         "country_name": "Mexico", "country_value": 14.92847},
        {"updated_at": 1591121709, "country_id": 350,
         "country_name": "Mexico", "country_value": 14.92847},
        {"updated_at": 1591121706, "country_id": 999,
         "country_name": "Russia", "country_value": 35.27485}]

filtered = (item['country_value'] for item in data if item['country_id'] == 999)

value = next(filtered, None)

print(value)
```